# How to access a server (TCP connection) running in a Virtual PC virtual machine (XP Mode) from the host system?

Tags: windows, windows-7, windows-xp, virtualization

I have a server application running in an XP Mode virtual machine in Virtual PC.  The host system is Windows 7.  I can't seem to connect a client running on the host system to this server (over a TCP connection), there is so response. I tried setting up the network connection in the VM as both NAT and Internal (restarting the VM each time), but there is no response from the VM (client never connects and ping reports that its unreachable).   I tried turning off both firewalls as well.  Any advice?

Thanks

Comment: I haven't used virtual but is there a bridged network option?  That is probably what you need.

Comment: are they on the same IP subnet, and have you checked routing tables if not ? could you post ipconfig/all for both ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the Virtual PC settings for XP Mode VM, set the NIC to the same network adapter name that you are using on the host OS.  NAT or Internal will prevent IP connectivity between the two.  Then do a ipconfig on both host and XP Mode computers and their IP addresses should be same subnet and you can use the IP of the XP Mode VM to access it (as long as it's FW is off or ports open).

Comment: This is a "bridged" mode, right? Where the VM and the host will share logical connections on the same ethernet interface, so the VM will be joining the same network as the host?   This is not ideal but it should work.   I was hoping to just have a private network of some kind for the VM.   Is there a way in windows to create a virtual only device not bound to any actual ethernet device (similar to a loopback on Linux) that the VM could then use?